# window.history.back() not working right in Chrome, works in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have 2 buttons <kbd>Submit</kbd>, which posts the data and gets back validation errors from the server, and a <kbd>Cancel</kbd> which calls `window.history.back()`.

I click <kbd>Submit</kbd> X number of times (post comes/stays on the page because of validation errors from server)

On **Chrome** I need to click <kbd>Cancel</kbd> X times to go back to the previous page.

On **Mozilla** I only need to click <kbd>Cancel</kbd> once.

I guess Chrome counts the POST requests/direct backs in the history but Mozilla does not. I am not familiar with how that works or jquery. Is there something I can do to fix this?

**EDIT**: Going to hard code the urls in the link as suggested. Will come back later to try and see if I can do this by sending the referring page url to the edit form to load into the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button, if no one beats me to it.

```
…
{{ Form::submit('Create', array('class'=>'btn btn-info')) }}
    <a href="{{ URL::previous() }}" class="back btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
{{ Form::close() }}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.back').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.history.back();
            return false;
        });
    });
    …
</script>
```

Comment: If you don't care about preserving the data why don't you just redirect wherever you want the user to go upon canceling?

Comment: At the start of the day, I was convinced that I would need to call the edit form from different places... but now I think I don't so! Thanks!

Comment: I've never used it myself, but you may be able to use `return Redirect::back()` to return the user to where ever it was that they came from.

Answer (score 5):

In case you ever need to use back again, the safe cross-browser option was to use history.go(-1);